# Is there a way to qualify property names when using object initializers?

Tags: c#, .net, initialization

Background: a class constructor can have parameters whose names are the same as its properties, and resolve the assignment using the `this` keyword. Simplified example:

```
public MyClass(string Thing1, string Thing2)
{
  this.Thing1 = Thing1;
  this.Thing2 = Thing2;
}
```

What about object initializers? I want to instantiate an object, setting properties `Amount` and `Percentage` from parameters of the same name passed to the current method.

[image]

How can I qualify `Amount` and `Percentage` to distinguish the object properties from the method parameters?

Comment: Can you give a short but complete example demonstrating the problem? It's not clear what the issue is at the moment.

Comment: [I can't seem to reproduce](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a73f248cb2da49cc26f). Could you provide a full example.

Comment: why don't you simply change the parameter names ?

Comment: @Selman22 Why do he need to change it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel to make it compile

Comment: @Selman22 That's not required, refer my answer please

Comment: @SriramSakthivel but you are not doing the same thing.Try placing the DoSomething method inside of TestClass

Comment: @Selman22 That still makes no difference, It works too

Comment: okey now I get it. I couldn't think that the reason was that stupid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're not using object initializer, instead you just have the braces with parameter assigned to itself.. With object initializers, it just works.

Here is the minimal repro:

```
private static void Dosomething(string Name)
{
    { Name = Name };//Assignment made to same variable error
    var test = new TestClass{ Name = Name };//Works fine
}

class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: duh... you're right, I'm calling a factory-type method and wasn't paying attention.